Can you measure kinetic energy on Blender?
I’m new to the forum and a layman when it comes to using Blender (I work with it for hobby very rarely), as such I’m in the dark about many features of the program.
I wanted to ask for the moment if you can use it as a simulator to run an animation and get figures of kinetic energy from it. I saw already from YT videos that Blender can be used to measure velocity and acceleration of a mesh, so technically what may lack is the mass of the mesh in order to get energy.
I know already that volume is measurable by the way - - that’s one of the few things I’m capable of obtaining from the program on my own - - so maybe there’s a way to get the mass of a given model and get all needed data?

The Mass is a user-defined value for a Rigid Body, in the Physics Properties panel. Is it what you are looking for ?

kinematic energy is E = 1/2mv*v. Mass is what you entered in physics property panel, v can be calculated via difference between the position of 2 frames. By that you can calculate E. You can search here for answers how you can calculate v of an object.

I see, thanks for the help.

May I recommend to read this post : How to measure velocity and acceleration in real time using geometry nodes in Blender? ? And my I suggest to replace the "3d-printing" tag with "geometry-nodes" ?

Alright, I will.

Additionally to my answer which @StefLAncien has linked to and what Chris said about the mass: since the 3D meshes are no real-life objects, of course you can calculate things like acceleration, velocity and volume in relation to the properties these meshes have in the 3D scene's frame of reference, but the mass is completely arbitrary and only dependent on your choice: is the object which you modeled a block of wood? Is it steel? Is it a ballon filled with air or helium? So no matter how you will calculate the kinetic energy, the result depends on your decision what the mass of the object is.
